# Sum list of dicts of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dicts, every value in a dict is a four-element list:

```py
my_dict=[
    {
      'prop1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'prop2': [1, 1, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      'prop1': [2, 3, 3, 1],
      'prop3': [1, 1, 0, 0]
    }
]
```

Is it possible to sum it up without writing explicit iteration?

I want to get:

```py
my_dict_sum={
      'prop1': [3, 5, 6, 5],
      'prop2': [1, 1, 0, 0],
      'prop3': [1, 1, 0, 0]
}
```

UPD: something like this works, but I wonder how to use `map` or `zip` or `functools` to do the same without writing two levels of iteration:

```py
my_dict_sum = {}
for val in my_dict:
  for key,counts in val.items():
    if key in my_dict_sum :
        sum_dict[key] = list(map(lambda x,y: x+y, my_dict_sum[key], counts))
    else:
        my_dict_sum[key] = counts
```

Comment: Without explicit iteration? What is this, a code golf challenge?

Comment: then why adding `loops` in tags?

Comment: You still have not provided a reason why you need to rewrite the code without explicit iterations, nor have you shown an attempt doing so.

Comment: it can be "beaten" without any for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Here is a horrific one-liner with no explicit loops. I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this. You **SHOULDN'T** do this. Assuming you don't count comprehension as explicit loops despite the presence of the word "for".

```py
from functools import reduce

output = {k: reduce(
    lambda a, b:
        map(lambda d, e:
            d+e, a, b[k] if k in b else [0,0,0,0]
        ),
        dicts, 
        [0, 0, 0, 0]
    )
    for k in reduce(
        lambda s, b:
            s | set(b.keys()),
        dicts, set()
    )
}
```

Here's a simpler version with explicit loops, that I feel is a lot clearer than your code so maybe that's sufficient.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dicts = [
    {
      'prop1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'prop2': [1, 1, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      'prop1': [2, 3, 3, 1],
      'prop3': [1, 1, 0, 0]
    }
]

output = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, 0, 0])

for d in dicts:
    for k, l in d.items():
        for i, v in enumerate(l):
            output[k][i] += v
```

Note that it will only work if all the lists have exactly four items. For handling the case where you don't know how many items are in the lists, you can do this slightly more complex version:

```py
output = defaultdict(list)

for d in dicts:
    for k, l in d.items():
        for i, v in enumerate(l):
            if i >= len(output[k]):
                output[k].append(v)
            else:
                output[k][i] += v
```

You *could* do this as a one-liner using `reduce` and `map` and a bunch of lambdas, but it would be an incomprehensible mess. If you're concerned about a bunch of loops inline in your code, just put it in a function and call the function.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in Python is that you generally shouldn't try to do things as one-liners unless you have a really good reason. A few examples of when you *should* use one-liners are simple comprehensions and such. `[n for n in numbers if n%2==0]` is the most Pythonic way of getting all even numbers in a list. Faster and easier to read than an explicit `for n in numbers; ...` loop. Functional tools like `map`, `reduce`, etc, have their place but you should (mostly) only use them when they increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that it's not about finding the most explicit, or more *pythonic*, or most performant approach, but you just curious whether it hypothetically can be achieved in any other alternative way, here a short trick without any mentioning of `for` loop:

```
from itertools import chain

d = {}
items_chain = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda d: list(d.items()), my_dicts))
list(map(lambda t, d=d: d.update([t]) if t[0] not in d else \
    d.update([(t[0], list(map(sum, zip(d[t[0]], t[1]))))]), items_chain))
print(d)
```

---

```
{'prop1': [3, 5, 6, 5], 'prop2': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'prop3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
probably the better way is to define your own dictionary using the builtin UserDict Class, like this:

```
from collections import UserDict
class mydict(UserDict):  
    def __add__(self, other):
        for k, v in other.items():
            if k in self.data:
                self.data[k] =  list(map(sum, zip_longest(self.data[k], other[k], fillvalue=0)))
            else:
                self.data[k] = other.data[k]
        return self
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self if other == 0 else self.__add__(other)
```

and now the input list to be converted to new mydict class:(this step could be skipped if data originally created as mydict instead of dict)

```
new_dict = [mydict(v) for v in my_dict]
```

now only thing you need to do is the sum:

```
sum(new_dict)

results:
{'prop1': [3, 5, 6, 5], 'prop2': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'prop3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
```

**previous solution:**

you could do somthing like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
for line in my_dict:
     for key, val in line.items():
        out[key] = list(map(sum, zip_longest(val, out[key], fillvalue=0)))
```

and results:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'prop1': [3, 5, 6, 5],
             'prop2': [1, 1, 0, 0],
             'prop3': [1, 1, 0, 0]})
```

Comment: Implementing your own class just to sum some numbers seems like over-building the solution.